# reactstrap ButtonDropdown not working

Tags: reactjs

I have no idea why my ButtonDropdown isn't working. I try to learn react, but I do not find the failure in my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
//Also when I try with import bootstrap it isn`t working
import {
 ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, 
 DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 this.toggle_dropdownRunde = this.toggle_dropdownRunde.bind(this);
 this.changeText_dropdownRunde = this.changeText_dropdownRunde.bind(this); 
 
    this.state = {
  dropdownRunde_Open: false,
  dropdownRunde_Text: "-- Wait for response --",
    }; 
  }
 
 toggle_dropdownRunde() {  
  this.setState({
    dropdownRunde_Open: !this.state.dropdownRunde_Open
  });
 } 
 
 changeText_dropdownRunde() { 
  this.setState({
   dropdownRunde_Text: "hello anything different"
  });
 }  
 
  render () {
      return (  
  <div>
     <ButtonDropdown 
    isOpen={this.state.dropdownRunde_Open}  
    toggle={this.toggle_dropdownRunde} >
    <DropdownToggle caret>
    { this.state.dropdownRunde_Text }
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem value="Round 1" onClick={this.changeText_dropdownRunde}>Round 1</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem value="Round 2" onClick={this.changeText_dropdownRunde}>Round 2</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
     </ButtonDropdown> 
  </div>
 );
  }
}

render((
    <App />
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="app" />
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Sorry, I didn`t get it running on JSFiddle (*shameOnMe*)

The problem is that my ButtonDropDown is shown correctly but it does not expand. So when I click on the button nothing changes. What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Package.Json (if needed):

```
"babel-core": "^6.25.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
"node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
"react-addons-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
"react-bootstrap-table": "^4.0.1",
"react-burger-menu": "^2.1.4",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
"webpack": "^3.4.1"
```

Comment: SOLUTION: After trying 3 hours, I found the solution in the issues list! [link]https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/542[/link] I feel really disappointed not reading the issue list earlier!

Comment: Correct link is https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/542